# How to sort results alphabetically in columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some table with users and table with codes. Every user has 4 codes. I need to return 4 codes for user with id 5234 but sorted alphabetically.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    --results sorted alphabetically
    <here_should_be 'aaa'> code1,
    <here should be 'bbb'> code2,
    <here should be 'ccc'> code3,
    <here should be 'ddd'> code4
FROM
    user bt 
    LEFT JOIN table_with_codes value_1 ON (bt.rk_id = value_1.rk_id AND value_1.code = 'code_1') --assume value_1.string_value return 'bbb'
    LEFT JOIN table_with_codes value_2 ON (bt.rk_id = value_2.rk_id AND value_2.code = 'code_2') --assume value_2.string_value return 'aaa'
    LEFT JOIN table_with_codes value_3 ON (bt.rk_id = value_3.rk_id AND value_3.code = 'code_3') --assume value_3.string_value return 'ddd'
    LEFT JOIN table_with_codes value_4 ON (bt.rk_id = value_4.rk_id AND value_4.code = 'code_4') --assume value_4.string_value return 'ccc'
 WHERE bt.id = 5234;
```

What is best way to do this?

Comment: why would you do this? looks strange solution for me, what situation would need this type of sort ? :\

Comment: @MrSimpleMind, I edited my example.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3646)

Before the OP's update - if the 4 values are in different columns of the same row of the same table:

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:
**Query 1**:

```
WITH data ( z1, z2, z3, z4 ) AS (
  SELECT 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc', 'ddd' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT LEAST( z1, z2, z3, z4 ) c1,
       CASE WHEN z1 <= z2 AND z2 <= z3 AND z2 <= z4 THEN z2
            WHEN z1 <= z3 AND z3 <= z2 AND z3 <= z4 THEN z3
            WHEN z1 <= z4 AND z4 <= z2 AND z4 <= z3 THEN z4
            WHEN z2 <= z1 AND z1 <= z3 AND z1 <= z4 THEN z1
            WHEN z2 <= z3 AND z3 <= z1 AND z3 <= z4 THEN z3
            WHEN z2 <= z4 AND z4 <= z1 AND z4 <= z3 THEN z4
            WHEN z3 <= z1 AND z1 <= z2 AND z1 <= z4 THEN z1
            WHEN z3 <= z2 AND z2 <= z1 AND z2 <= z4 THEN z2
            WHEN z3 <= z4 AND z4 <= z1 AND z4 <= z2 THEN z4
            WHEN z4 <= z1 AND z1 <= z3 AND z1 <= z4 THEN z1
            WHEN z4 <= z2 AND z2 <= z1 AND z2 <= z3 THEN z2
            WHEN z4 <= z3 AND z3 <= z1 AND z3 <= z2 THEN z3 END AS c2,
       CASE WHEN z1 >= z2 AND z2 >= z3 AND z2 >= z4 THEN z2
            WHEN z1 >= z3 AND z3 >= z2 AND z3 >= z4 THEN z3
            WHEN z1 >= z4 AND z4 >= z2 AND z4 >= z3 THEN z4
            WHEN z2 >= z1 AND z1 >= z3 AND z1 >= z4 THEN z1
            WHEN z2 >= z3 AND z3 >= z1 AND z3 >= z4 THEN z3
            WHEN z2 >= z4 AND z4 >= z1 AND z4 >= z3 THEN z4
            WHEN z3 >= z1 AND z1 >= z2 AND z1 >= z4 THEN z1
            WHEN z3 >= z2 AND z2 >= z1 AND z2 >= z4 THEN z2
            WHEN z3 >= z4 AND z4 >= z1 AND z4 >= z2 THEN z4
            WHEN z4 >= z1 AND z1 >= z3 AND z1 >= z4 THEN z1
            WHEN z4 >= z2 AND z2 >= z1 AND z2 >= z3 THEN z2
            WHEN z4 >= z3 AND z3 >= z1 AND z3 >= z2 THEN z3 END AS c3,
       GREATEST( z1, z2, z3, z4 ) c4
FROM   data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3646/0)**:

```
|  C1 |  C2 |  C3 |  C4 |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd |
```

After the OP's update - if the 4 values are in different rows of the same table:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29c46/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( id, rk_id ) AS
SELECT 5234, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_with_codes (rk_id, code, string_value ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'code1', 'bbb' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'code2', 'ddd' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'code3', 'aaa' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'code4', 'ccc' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH ordered_codes ( rk_id, idx, string_value ) AS (
  SELECT rk_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY rk_id ORDER BY string_value ),
         string_value
  FROM   table_with_codes
)
SELECT u.id,
       MAX( CASE idx WHEN 1 THEN string_value END ) AS c1,
       MAX( CASE idx WHEN 2 THEN string_value END ) AS c2,
       MAX( CASE idx WHEN 3 THEN string_value END ) AS c3,
       MAX( CASE idx WHEN 4 THEN string_value END ) AS c4
FROM   users u
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ordered_codes o
       ON ( u.rk_id = o.rk_id )
WHERE  u.id = 5234
GROUP BY u.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29c46/1/0)**:

```
|   ID |  C1 |  C2 |  C3 |  C4 |
|------|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 5234 | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd |
```

Comment: OMG, this code looks horribly.. is it the best way? ;>

Comment: That depends on how you structure your data: if the data is in different columns of the same row then yes it may look horrible but it is the best way; however, if the data is in different rows (rather than columns) then see my update.

Comment: And if the data is structured like the first option and you have to deal with `NULL` values then it will get even more convoluted.